# Magento Category Product List Sort By Bestseller Options

Tags: php, magento

I m trying get Best Seller option in select box at Category product listing.

I have already extended

```
class Mymodule_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar
{

    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
    }

    public function getAvailableOrders()
    {
        $this->_availableOrder['bestseller'] = $this->__('Best Seller');
        return $this->_availableOrder;
    }


}
```

After that , I got Best Seller option in select box.
But, I don't known how to get it work.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is 'Best Seller'? Is it a custom product attribute?

Comment: Well, No . That would be collect data from report and join the products of category. that would be top selling products of that category or something

Comment: "After that, I got Best Seller option in select box." - this means you create appropriate layout update and now your Mymodule_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar block is used instead of Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar block on all category pages, right? You don't know how to prepare products collection for this your new 'best seller' order or what?

Comment: Yes, I got Best Seller Option in select box. But when I choose the option I would like to sort the product by best seller. Like Join report and product then order by top seller product. The problem is . i don't known where or which file i have to extend to do the sorting things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need extend setCollection() too:

```
public function getAvailableOrders()
{
    $this->_availableOrder['bestseller'] = $this->__('Best Seller');
    return $this->_availableOrder;
}


public function setCollection($collection)
{
    // ...
    if ($this->getCurrentOrder()) {
        if ($this->getCurrentOrder() == 'bestseller') {
            // add needed joins to collection here to get 'bestseller' column in collection
        }
        $this->_collection->setOrder($this->getCurrentOrder(), $this->getCurrentDirection());
    }
    return $this;
}
```

Btw, do you know that `$this->__('Best Seller');` is bad style? As you know, `$this->__()` is shortcut for current module data helper __() method. But if someone will extended your block in another module - that module data helper will be used to translate 'Best Seller' string to other languages. It is evident that in his module he may not have translation for 'Best Seller' string. That's why you must always use `Mage::helper('your_module/data')->__()` for translation.

Comment: thanks Zyava , it's useful . But , I still getting stack in joining current product from category and report top selling products.

Comment: @ThureinSoe: have you been able to find the solution?