# Magento order products by SKU

Tags: sorting, magento, product

I would like my store products to be displayed in SKU (ascending) order by default when looking at the category product listing pages. Can someone please tell me how to:

1. Make this the default sort option.
2. Add SKU as a user selectable option on the product listing pages.

Can anyone help please?

Cheers!

Comment: what version of magento are we talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having been around this issue a little, I found out that you can add SKU as an option in the Manage Attributes menu in Admin. Having done that, and then set it to be the default in System > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog > Product Listing Sort By.

It turns out that the company I hired to produce my website template had overridden the toolbar.php file, and there was a hardcoded list of order by options in there.
Commenting that list out (basically reverting that function back to the default template version) now shows up the SKU option in the list.

I next need to figure out how to make that be the default - something else I guess is over-riding that as it *should* be the default based on the settings I have in place now.

Thanks for all the help here.
Cheers,
Rob

Comment: That is for checkout also? Sort order?

Answer (score 5):

I hope this works the same for 1.4.0.1 as it does for 1.6.0.0 because it is really easy and you don't have to touch any code:

1. In the admin panel, go to Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attributes
2. Find the attribute labeled SKU
3. In it, under Frontend Properties, change the "Use for Sorting in Product Listing" to "Yes" and save
4. Go to System > Configuration and click on the Catalog section
5. Under Frontend, change the "Product Listing Sort by" to "SKU" and save

You can also change the default product listing for each category in Catalog > Manage Categories under the Display Settings tab of your selected category.

Comment: I have done this but It does not work in checkout/cart

Answer (score 0):

See this question and answer [Magento Category Product List Sort By Bestseller Options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6422179/magento-category-product-list-sort-by-bestseller-options/). Because sku is table column, you don't need extend setCollection() method.

Comment: I don't quite follow... do I need to be adding code into toolbar.php? Or is there some xml file that I can add SKU into to accomplish this?